# Getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input' Issue when run composer-rest-server command

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I deployed/updated the BNA file. I am getting below mentioned issue when running the composer-rest-server command

Command

```
composer-rest-server -c admin@project -n always -w true -p 3000
```

Issue

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at Promise (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server/server.js:53:32)
>       at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/server/server.js:39:12)
>       at module.exports.promise.then (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/cli.js:124:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:496:3

result for `npm ls -g --depth=0`

[image]

Please give a solution to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly something wrong in your BNA ? can you post the model and script? Also what version of composer modules?  can you do an `npm ls -g --depth=0` and post the results thx

Comment: so you imported the admin@project card ? What happens if you deploy (separately) a basic-sample-network and try run the REST server for that (using the admin card you create for that,  from your `composer network deploy` command for that network and then - subsequently - run  `composer card import` and `composer network ping` to get credentials stored for the admin card. This will establish whether the issues lies with something in the `project` network or not (ie if the REST server works successfully for basic sample we'll be able to focus on `project` specifics).

Comment: Hai, I tried with basic-sample-network applcaition. Same composer-rest-server return the issue.    $ composer-rest-server -c admin@basic-sample-network -n always -w true -p 3002

Comment: I am getting the issue when connecting the system using putty application.

Comment: what is the output of `composer network ping` ?